# monacaでテンキーを実装するには（"."を使った小数を入力したい）

Tags: monaca, cordova

自作テンキーを作成する他ないのでしょうか？inputで

```
type="tel" pattern="\d+(\.\d*)?"
```

とすると、* ; ,は入力できるテンキーが出るのですが、ドットが入力できません。
どうすればいいでしょうか？

http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/showing-decimal-point-and-negative-sign-in-numeric-keyboard/13488/4

Answer (score 1):

はい、入力のレイアウトに拘るのであれば自作するしかありません。
想像しているのは3x4の入力フォームですよね？

質問に記載されている`type="tel"`は電話番号に関係する文字列しか入力できません。
(※数値、＊＃＋)
また、`type="number"`ではレイアウトが想定の物と違うものになってしまうかと思います。
INPUTのみで制御するのは難しいでしょう。

あと`pattern`の要素を追加しておりますが、
それは入力値を保証するものではございません。
`pattern`で制限をかけても入力できます。
此方は当てにならないので私は使用しておりません。
(※と言うより使用する用途が見つかりません。)

Comment: pattern属性はHTML5でフォーム送信時のバリデーションに使われますが、スマホは軒並み対応してなかったような http://qiita.com/ka215/items/795a179041c705bef03b